# Adding a File or Folder to a Git Repo in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I want simply add a new File or Folder to an existing Repo in my Eclipse.

I tried the following (add index on the file and folder), but nothing happens.

Can someone help me.

[image]

Comment: In the _Git Stagging_ view you have to commit the indexed/staged files. In Git only files, but not empty folders can be committed.

Comment: In my case it was because I had a folder in the git ignore file. My fault. Sorry for that. I realized this when trying to add in git bash. In eclipse no message appeared.

Comment: For ignored folders no _Add to Index_ entry is shown to me. Do you use the latest version of EGit (Eclipse 2019-03 contains EGit 5.3)?

Comment: very interesting. It showed to me. How can I find the version.

Comment: In _Help > About Eclipse_ click on the _Eclipse EGit_ icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Git, a new file must first be added to the index (also called staging area) and then committed before the file becomes part of the history:

1. Add files:

   - Right-click and choose *Team > Add to Index* or
   - in the *Git Staging* view move the file from *Unstaged Changes* down to *Staged Changes*
2. Commit files: **In the *Git Staging* view enter a *Commit Message* and click *Commit***

Result: In the *History* view a new commit containing the files is shown.

Please note in Git (in contrast to e.g. SVN) only files, but not empty folders can be committed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties on that folder to get its path.

Switch to command line, and do a `git status` (if you have Git installed), to check if the folder and its content is actually in a Git repo (or if only "`src`" is):
Chec at least if you see a `.git` folder above the folder you want to add to the index, you should be able to do so from Eclipse.
But if not, that would explain why adding it does nothing.

Comment: The question is not about the Git command line but about the Git support in Eclipse (which does not require the Git command line to be installed).

Comment: @howlger I know, but when in doubt, always fall back to the command line to understand what is going on. Then switch back to the IDE.

Comment: Where do you know if the command line Git is installed? Why install and use a tool other than the one mentioned in the question? From the screenshot you can see that a `.git` folder must exist.

Comment: @howlger You don't need Git installed to apply my answer. From the screenshot, I see src is tracked. I am not sure about the other folders, hence my suggestion. Again: when in doubt, switch back to command line first.

Comment: `git status` returns `'git' is not recognized...` if the Git command line is not installed.